# Doing a join on null = null on dates

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to join two tables on date fields

```
INNER JOIN ##MetricBase
ON  A.MetricID = ##MetricBase.MetricID
AND     A.ImportDate = ##MetricBase.ImportDate
```

I also want the data to match if the dates are null.

Is there a cleaner way than

```
 INNER JOIN ##MetricBase
 ON    A.MetricID = ##MetricBase.MetricID
 AND   (A.ImportDate = ##MetricBase.ImportDate OR
        A.ImportDate IS NULL AND  ##MetricBase.ImportDate IS NULL)
```

**Addendum**

Some comments suggested that I avoid null dates. This query is a part of a grouping set

```
 GROUP BY GROUPING SETS(
(BossID, ID, ImportDate),
(BossID, ImportDate),
(BossID),
(BossID, ID),
(ImportDate),
()
)
```

Nulls are going to be a part of the dataset

Comment: get rid of the nulls in your table and give the column a default value  of a bigining of time or armageddon date :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an [MS Connect Request](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/286422/add-language-and-optimizer-support-for-iso-distinct-predicate) currently out to support `IS DISTINCT FROM`, which is the proper, ISO way of doing it. The lack of support is currently a pain in the neck, and the way you're already doing it is in fact technically correct.

Somebody did figure out a [clever workaround](http://web.archive.org/web/20180422151947/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/06/22/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.aspx) but it's not applicable to all scenarios. In your case I believe it would be written as:

```
INNER JOIN ##MetricBase
ON A.MetricID = ##MetricBase.MetricID
AND EXISTS(SELECT A.ImportDate INTERSECT SELECT ##MetricBase.ImportDate)
```

Supposedly, recent versions of SQL Server are pretty good at optimizing this.

Comment: Or instead of a separate equality condition `INNER JOIN ##MetricBase ON EXISTS(SELECT A.MetricID, A.ImportDate INTERSECT SELECT ##MetricBase.MetricID, ##MetricBase.ImportDate)`

Comment: @MartinSmith: That's functionally the same but I wonder if the query plan would be better, worse, or the same? I think it could be worse if there's an index on MetricID and SQL Server decides it's non-sargable inside the `INTERSECT`.

Comment: It will give the same plan with an equality expression.

Answer (score 1):

Logically you cannot reduce that further, because for many other reasons `null` is not equal to anything, even itself.

A syntactic trick to keep in it in one predicate would be to use `COALESCE` with a 'magic' value. Without running tests I don't know what impact if any, this would have on performance. I believe your explicit statement of both conditions (equal OR both null) is clearer and more maintainable. But the for the sake of ideas, here's the `COALESCE` version:

```
DECLARE @nullDate date = '04-02-4242';

...
ON A.MetricID   = ##MetricBase.MetricID
AND COALESCE(A.ImportDate           , @nullDate) = 
    COALESCE(##MetricBase.ImportDate, @nullDate)
```

Comment: while logically correct, true, and a good answer.  It is also a very poor performing query as it will execute the COALESCE function on every row.  Which may not be a problem based on the dataset - not something that we can foresee here.

Comment: @DanAndrews Yep, I agree. As I even state in my answer this is probably not a "good" idea, but it is an *interesting* one which correctly solves the technical problem, and I think there's value in that.

Comment: As well as performance issues it relies on there being a "magic" value that can never legitimately appear in the data. Or will join incorrect rows.

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes. So as always one must choose the "magic" value carefully -- and it will still be a dirty trick